# Java class design for redundant variable property

Tags: java, design-patterns

Consider

```java
Class A {
    private Map<String, String> AXMap;
    private Map<String, String> A1Map;
    private Map<String, String> A2Map;
    private Map<String, String> A3Map;
}
```

```java
ClassB {
    public void someMethod() {

    List<ClassA> classAList = new ArrayList...
    for i..0 to n {
        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        populate A1Map;
        populate A2Map;
        populate A3Map;
        classAList.add(classA)
    }
}
```

The crude logic above is just that `A1Map`, `A2Map`, `A3Map` are populated for each `ClassA` of the loop and added to the final list. My design question is `AXmap` remains the same for all the iterations. Even if I populate once, the same redundant `AXmap` is in every object of `ClassA` list.   I do need the `AXmap` along with other maps. Is there a better java design principle. All I could think was in terms of inheritance, final or Move `AXMap` to separate class and add as composition etc

Comment: Two questions. (1) Is it ever valid to have two objects of type `ClassA` that have a different `AXMap` value? (2) If you change the `AXMap` on one instance of `ClassA`, should that also update `AXMap` for all other instances of `ClassA`?

Comment: Let me answer in a different way, I have a rest end point, so for every request the AXMap differs. Every request performs the for loop. For every Class A object for a given request the AXMap remains the same thru sending the response.

Comment: you can use ) `List<Map<String,String>>` and if  keys are not same then 2) put all details in single map. If its complex, then (3) either details are missing (4)  try to keep it simple as possible

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use static method, thus AXMap will becomes a class variable, bit not an object variable, e.g. will be shared among all the objects of the class. The less trivial way to make it as a singleton, and use it among all object of the class. I would say the easiest way to make it a singleton is to introduce spring in the project, and make a spring bean out of the AXMap. The last approach will gives you some perks out of the box such as thread safety.

Comment: Introducing Spring in order to make `AXMap` a singleton seems like it's probably overkill for this problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their suggestions. Appreciate it. I will check out the suggestions. At this point I am little confused so I will not be able to accept a particular answer

Answer (score 0):

As you point out in your comment, Singleton doesn't fit here as you will require multiple `AXMap` objects. The **Multiton** pattern may help, which is essentially a registry of Singleton objects. Off the top of my head, the access key could be the request type. If the requested `AXMap` object doesn't exist, it is created, otherwise the existing one is returned. This seems a nice fit to the problem, if I've understood it correctly.